# What happens to uncollected item drops in Outriders?

Tags: outriders

When items drop I have to press <kbd>E</kbd> to pick them up and it seems to hoover up items based on my loot setting.

However what happens to items I do not pick up, if I happen to miss them or leave them behind because I'm fighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings you can set up auto-pickup for certain rarities. The Default is Purple or higher, iirc.

When moving to the next zone, this system will pick up anything at that rarity. if it does not meet the threshold the item is ignored.

Comment: Pickup? Add it to my inventory or stash you mean?